# Using arg[v] as int? - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, argv

I'm trying to pass arguments into and integer variable at the start of my program in xcode using Objective C. So far most methods I've found have just given me a variety of error messages or crashed my VM.

```
int numcols, numrows;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {

    if (argc != 3){
        NSLog(@"%2s", "Wrong number of arguments");
        exit(1);
    }

    //numrows = (int)(argv[1] - '0'); 
    //numcols = (int)(argv[2] - '0'); These lines cause a crash
    numrows = 3;
    numcols = 4;
```

I want numrows to take the first argument and numcols to take the second. I went into the settings in xcode to change the starting arguments to 3 and 4, but if I check them or print them they come out as random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your question is not clear, how much i understand i can say. As argc means argument count and argv means argument value. If you want to cast char to int. try this

```
[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", argv[2]] intValue];
```

Comment: I might wrap the - 0 in parenthesis as opposed to brackets (it's not a method call)

Comment: When I use this I get the error "Bad receiver type 'const char *'. But this is what I want to achieve.

Comment: why are you subtracting 0..why not try only this numrows = [argv[2] intValue]; ? and i know its not a method call..its only casting.

Comment: try this [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", argv[2]] intValue]; if this doesn't work..try my edited answer too and let me know.

Comment: This comment got it for me. Thanks a lot! Too many hours were spent on this. Except I had to use %s instead of %c, so the final line was: numrows = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", argv[2]] intValue];

Comment: @Sulthan thanks for correcting me..Appreciate your suggestion..thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`argv` is an array of *C strings*. You cannot just cast a string to an integer, you need to *parse* the string to produce the integer value it represents.

You could write code to do this yourself, but fortunately there are library functions which handle this, for example see [`strtol`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/strtol.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/strtol) which will parse a string and produce a `long`.

HTH